# How to set 3D coordinate system by PyOpenGL

Tags: python, pyopengl

How to set 3D coordinate system by PyOpenGL in Python like the picture below? Just like `fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.set_zlim(-1,1)` in `matplotlib`. 
[image]

And how to plot 3D curves?
Anybody can help me?I will be very grateful.
I'm a new fish...